# Way to find Distinct values from a table by a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Here is a table consisting of data like below:

```
StandardName|Username    |RType
------------|------------|--------
Department  |Department  |  Position
Division    |Division    |  Entity
Division    |Division    |  Position
Plant       |Plant       |  Entity
Section     |Section     |  Position
SubDivision |Sub-Division|  Entity
SubDivision |Subdivision |  Position
SubSection  |Subsection  |  Position
Unit        |Unit        |  Entity
```

I want all the StandardName and UserName followed by Rtype = 'Entity' and In case of Rtype = 'Position' it will only get the StandardName those are not associated with RType  'Entity'

For doing this I did the query like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.StandardName, u.UserName ,ISNULL(e.RType,'position') AS RType
from (
     SELECT  DISTINCT StandardName,UserName
     from Table1 AS ee where   RType = 'Entity'  
     UNION
     SELECT  DISTINCT StandardName, UserName
     from Table1 AS pp where  RType = 'position' 
) u
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     select UserName,StandardName,RType 
     from Table1 WHERE RType='Entity' 
) e on e.StandardName = u.StandardName
 ORDER BY Rtype
```

Then the output is

```
StandardName|Username    |RType
------------|------------|--------
Division    |Division    |  Entity
Plant       |Plant       |  Entity      
SubDivision |Sub-Division|  Entity
SubDivision |Subdivision |  Entity       
Unit        |Unit        |  Entity
Department  |Department  |  Position
Section     |Section     |  Position
SubSection  |Subsection  |  Position
```

Here in Case of 'SubDivision' it appears two times, whereas it needs to appear one time with the 'Entity' RType.

The Expected output should be--

```
StandardName|Username    |RType
------------|------------|--------
Division    |Division    |  Entity
Plant       |Plant       |  Entity      
SubDivision |Sub-Division|  Entity            
Unit        |Unit        |  Entity
Department  |Department  |  Position
Section     |Section     |  Position
SubSection  |Subsection  |  Position
```

The SQLFIDDLE [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3fe28/17/0)

Comment: Usernames `Sub-Division` and `Subdivision` should be equal, aren't they ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sql statement translated from your requirements:

```
 -- gimme all things that are entity
 select StandardName, UserName, RType 
   from Table1
   where RType = 'Entity'  
 union   
 -- and all things that have no entity-entry
   select StandardName, UserName, RType from Table1 as k
   where rtype = 'Position' and not exists (
       select 1 
       from table1 as t 
       where t.standardname = k.standardname 
         and t.rtype = 'Entity'  
   )
```

does not have your "distincs" in it, but you get the result of:

```
StandardName    UserName        RType
----------------------------------------
Division        Division        Entity
Plant           Plant           Entity
SubDivision     Sub-Division    Entity
Unit            Unit            Entity
Department      Department      Position
Section         Section         Position
SubSection      Subsection      Position
```

You do not have any duplicate `'Entity'`-entries - so no distinct required.

Answer (score 2):

This is a prioritization query.  Patrick's method is a good method, particularly when there are only two types.

Another method uses `row_number()`:

```
select e.StandardName, e.Username, e.RType
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by StandardName
                                order by (case RType when 'Entity' then 1 when 'Position' then 2 else 3 end)
                               ) as seqnum
      from employees e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

For each StandardName you want the row with 'Entity', but if this doesn't exist the row with 'Position'. This is a simple task for ROW_NUMBER:

```
with cte as 
 ( 
   select
      StandardName
     ,Username
     ,RType
     ,row_number() 
      over (partition by StandardName  -- for each StandardName
            order by RType) as rn      -- sort to get Entity first
   from Table1
 )
select
   StandardName
  ,Username
  ,RType
from cte
where rn = 1
order by
   RType
  ,Username
;
```

See [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/201d9/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
select * from Employees 
where rtype = 'Entity' 
or
standardname in (
select standardname from Employees 
where rtype = 'Position' and 
standardname not in 
(select standardname from employees where rtype = 'Entity'))
order by rtype,standardname
```